Find $\lim x_ny_n$ for $x_{n+1} = x_n +\sqrt{1+x_n^2}$ and $y_{n+1} = \dfrac{y_n}{1+\sqrt{1+y_n^2}}$
Let $x_1 = y_1 = \sqrt{3}$, $x_{n+1} = x_n + \sqrt{1+x_n^2}$ and $y_{n+1} = \dfrac{y_n}{1+\sqrt{1+y_n^2}}$. Find $\lim (x_ny_n)$.
I predicted that $x_n$ and $y_n$ can be written as $\sin,\cos,\tan$ but I can't find the general one. Can anyone help me?

Hint:  $x+\sqrt{1+x^2} = \cot(\frac12\cot^{-1}(x))$ and $\frac{y}{1+\sqrt{1+y^2}} = \tan(\frac12\tan^{-1}(y))$.

If we start by computing few first terms of $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ we can see that $y_2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}=\frac{1}{x_1}, y_3=\frac{1}{2+\sqrt3}=\frac{1}{x_2}$ which may suggest that $y_{n+1}=\frac{1}{x_n}$. Actually it can be easily proved by induction: we have already shown the first step and then assuming $y_{n+1}=\frac{1}{x_n}$ we have
$$ y_{n+2}=\frac{y_{n+1}}{1+\sqrt{1+y_{n+1}^2}}=\frac{\frac{1}{x_n}}{1+\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x_n^2}}}=\frac{1}{x_n+\sqrt{1+x_n^2}}=\frac{1}{x_{n+1}}. $$
Now finding the limit is easy:
$$ x_ny_n=x_n\cdot \frac{1}{x_{n-1}}=\frac{x_{n-1}+\sqrt{1+x_{n-1}^2}}{x_{n-1}}=1+\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x_{n-1}^2}} $$
so $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}x_ny_n=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\left(1+\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x_{n-1}^2}}\right)=2$
because it's easy to see that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}x_n=+\infty.$

Your solution is amazing, I think that this problem can only be solved by using trigonometry

It is possible to bound the value. First of all, note that $x_{n+1}$ is increasing in $x_n$ (this is obvious). Likewise, $y_{n+1}$ is increasing in $y_n$ for positive $y_n$ (you can see this by writing it as $y_{n+1}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{y_n}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{y_n^2}+1}}$).
Now consider the case where instead $y_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$, so $y_1=\frac{1}{x_1}$. We can prove by induction that $y_n=\frac{1}{x_n}$ for all $n$. The induction step would rely on the fact that $\frac{1}{y_{n+1}}=\frac{1}{y_n}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{y_n^2}+1}$. In that case, $x_ny_n=1$ for all $n$. Since the starting value of $y_1$ is lower than our actual value, it follows that in  the real sequence we always have $x_ny_n\geq 1$.
Moreover, suppose that we multiply $y_1$ by 3. Then we can see in the definition of $y_2$ that the result of this is that $y_2$ is multiplied by some factor less than 3 (since $\sqrt(1+y_1^2)$ increases if $y_1$ is bigger). Continuing this argument, we conclude that if $y_1$ becomes 3 times bigger, then for any $n$, $y_n$ is less than 3 times bigger. So we conclude that in our original sequence, starting with $y_1=\sqrt{3}$ instead of $y_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$, any future $y_n$ gets less than 3 times bigger.
In conclusion, for our sequence, $1\leq x_ny_n\leq 3$. Sharper bounds can be computed by taking later terms since $x_ny_n$ should be decreasing by the above logic. It then follows that the limit should exist and be between 1 and 3.
